# Reading Data from different locations through a function

Tags: r

I am pretty much new to R and was struggling with the below scenario :
    I need to write a function which reads data from different locations on the PC(like downloads,documents,desktop etc). Each file in these locations have a unique id. So the function would take the id and location as arguments. It would somewhat be like this :

```
 onefunc <- function(directory,id)
  {
    y <- read.csv("directory/id")
  }
```

I need to pass the directory and ID to the read function. But the above code throws an error -   cannot open file 'directory/id': No such file or directory. What do I need to pass in read.csv exactly?

Comment: `read.csv(file.path(directory, id))` or `read.csv(paste(directory, id, sep="/"))`

Answer (score 2):

What you have right now inside the function is a string (sequence of characters). R does not recognize these as variables. You need the variables `directory` and `id` together into a string. A host of options is available to do just that:

- `sprintf('%s/%s', directory, id)`
- `paste(directory, id, sep = '/')`
- `file.path(directory, id)`, is specifically meant for constructing file paths. Other functions are generic string building functions. I would recommend using this function in your case as it is most specific to your situation, and will work across all platforms.

You can then feed this string into `read.csv` to perform the actual reading.